# Asterisk TDM Out Channel Not Recording

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to use the monitor command to record a TDM extension, but only the in chnnnel is being recorded. The out channel is 44 bytes and obviously no audio within. However, when monitoring a SIP or IAX phone, no problems exist. Is there some configuration I'm missing for distinguishing between TDM and SIP/IAX for recording?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very weird **workaround** but, I added a dialplan to run MixMonitor on the connecting extension prior to monitoring via AMI.  Any suggestions as to a reason why I need to do this?